# Server Client Communication via Internet (Java)

Tags: java, networking, tcp, server, router

I have written a simple Java TCP Server and a Client (See below).

The idea is quite simple: the Client sends a message to the Server the  Server reads it, modify it and sends it back to the client.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

public class ServerTest2 { 

public static void main(String[] argv) { 

  try { 
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000); // Create Socket and bind to port 2000
      System.out.println("Created");
      Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); //Wait for client and if possible accept 
      System.out.println("Connection accepted");
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())); // for outputs
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); // for inputs

      String request; // requst/input of client
      String answer; // the answer for the client

      System.out.println("Start Waiting");
      request = br.readLine(); //Wait for input from client 
      answer = "answer to "+request; 
      bw.write(answer);  // Send answer to client
      System.out.println("send");
      bw.newLine(); 
      bw.flush(); 

      //Shut everything down
      bw.close(); 
      br.close(); 
      clientSocket.close(); 
      serverSocket.close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
      System.out.println(e); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

The **Client** Implementation

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

public class ClientTest2 { 

public static void main(String[] argv) { 

  try { 
      String host = "185.75.149.8"; //public ip of router
      Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host,2000);  //Create and connect Socket to the host on port 2000

      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())); // for outputs
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); // for inputs

      String answer; 
      String request = "HelloWorld";

      bw.write(request); //Write to server
      bw.newLine(); 
      bw.flush(); 
      System.out.println("Waiting");
      answer = br.readLine(); //Wait for answer

      System.out.println("Host = "+host); 
      System.out.println("Echo = "+answer); 

      //Shut eveything down
      bw.close(); 
      br.close(); 
      clientSocket.close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
      System.out.println(e); 
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly on my local network.

Now I want to use it via the Internet so I installed Port Forwarding on **Port 2000** in my Router which sends it to **Port 2000** of my PC.
My PC is directly connected to my Router without any Subnets in between.

The Problem is that the Server does not accept the `connection(Stops at serverSocket.accept())`.

It does not throw an Exception it just waits forever.
The Client does also not throw an Exception (If the Port isn't open it would throw a **Connection refused** Exception)

This means that the Port Forwarding should work (I have also tested whether the port is open with a Webtool (its open)).

But strangely the Client stops waiting after about 10 seconds and continues with the program.

Since the Port Forwarding should work and my Code works fine in my local Network I absolutely don't know how or where I could find the problem.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Id probably deactivate my firewall for a moment to test it. You could try this if you can take the risk

Comment: You can also check if the port is openly reachable from outside your network. Just google something like "portcheck" and you should find websites that check that. (canyouseeme is the most famous example I guess).

Comment: Also I did just check it and the port is open on your IP. Also you might not want to post your IP openly.

Comment: MyWindows Firewall isnt active anyways. And the routers firewall is not active at pport 2000 ecause of Port Forwarding. So that should not be a problem... I have also already checked the accessebilty of the port and its open(as Ben can confirm ;D)

Comment: Port forwarding is for NAT, but that has nothing to do with the firewall. NAT and firewall are two very different processes. You would need to port forward for NAT, and you would need to set up a firewall rule to allow outside to inside.